# Javascript object literal name rule

Tags: javascript, object, literals

I would like to use dot notation in an object literal name but IE returns an error: "Expected ':'" at line 16 after the partial 'my' statement (3rd from the bottom).  There has to be a way to do something like this.  Why is this returning an error?

```
<script language="javascript">
var my = {};
my.dataGridColumns = [];
var tmpArr = [];    
var columnData = [];

columnData.push("a");

my.dataGridColumns.push({
    id: 1,
    name: test
});

tmpArr.push({
    my.dataGridColumns[0].name: columnData[0]
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please note where line `16` is.

Comment: IE9, also happening in Chrome 16.0.912.77.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can treat an object like an associative array using `[]`. You can take advantage of this to access property names dynamically.

How about:

```
var obj = { };
obj[my.dataGridColumns[0].name] = columnData[0];

tmpArr.push(obj);
```